# Carousel won't resize on phone deice to show entire image

Tags: html, css

looks fine on computer, on tablet in horizontal it seems to crop into image "center"..  on phones it crops into center even more not showing all the image.

code in source code view (dreamweaver)

```
  <main id="main" class="site-main">
    <section id="carousel-1" class="carousel slide section-slide" data-ride="carousel">

                       <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active" style="background: url(images/bg-1.jpg);">
          <div class="container"><img src="http://roncartist.com/images/copyright_protected-1.png" alt="First slide"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item" style="background: url(images/bg-2.jpg);">
          <div class="container"><img src="http://placehold.it/640x340" alt="Second slide"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item" style="background: url(images/bg-3.jpg);">
          <div class="container"><img src="http://placehold.it/640x340" alt="Third slide"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-1" data-slide="prev"><span class="fa fa-chevron-left"></span></a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-1" data-slide="next"><span class="fa fa-chevron-right"></span></a>
```

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNLND.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You have to aplly `background-size:cover` to the element `.item`
It stretch the background image to completely cover the content area.
Let me know if works.

Comment: Roy I think the problem is the carousel is not sizing down and was thinking putting it in a .wrapper might contain it to the responsiveness of page?